# C# enabling menu item

Tags: c#, try-catch, menuitem

I have a try-catch statement in reference to downloading a file. When the file is downloaded, I then enable one of my menu items then turn off a timer set to retry the download in one minute.

My problem is that for some reason my `trafficManagementToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;` line is activating the catch statement even though the menu item is being enabled. The file correctly downloads and when I comment out that line, it works perfectly. But every time I run it, I get the "error" message box and the timer is not disabled even though the menu item correctly enables after the download is complete.

Any ideas?

```
try
{
    ////downloads Data

    string address = "http://website.file.txt";
    string filename = "vsd.txt";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile(address, filename);
    trafficManagementToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}
catch
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("error", "test");
}
```

Comment: Is this code running on a thread other than the main GUI thread?

Comment: maybe first see what the exception is?

Comment: yes it's in the background. What's strange is that the second time it runs (after the timer re-starts it) it works perfectly

Comment: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: okay so yes I see what the problem is, but I am having tough time understanding the invoke stuff

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a basic example of the Invoke stuff.  Leave a comment if it's still puzzling.

Comment: Get right out of the habit of using `catch {}`. It prevents you from learning about the bugs you're introducing into the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what the exception is, but I'd guess that you're running your download routine in a background thread, is that right?  You can only access controls from the thread that created them: the main UI thread.  Accessing a control such as a ToolStripMenuItem from a background thread will cause an exception.

If this is the case, use the Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke method to run the `.Enabled = true` call on the ToolStripMenuItem's thread.  To do this, you'll need a Control (unfortunately ToolStripMenuItem is only a Component).  I'll assume you can get a reference to the containing Form from somewhere.  Now you can write this:

```
Action enableAction = delegate() { trafficManagementToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true; }
form.BeginInvoke(enableAction);
```

This causes the `enableAction` to run on the correct UI thread for `form`.

Comment: I'm using my psychic powers to predict itowlson's pychic debugging will fix the issue.

Comment: *Never* use Invoke. Always BeginInvoke.

Comment: "Never" is too strong.  But you're right, it's good to get into the habit of using BeginInvoke unless there's a specific reason to prefer Invoke.  I'll update the example.

Answer (score 4):

change your catch to be

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    timer1.Enabled = true; 
    MessageBox.Show("error", ex.Message); 
}
```

This will at least give you the actual error message.

I'm guessing it's because you are not running in the UI thread and need to use Control.Invoke, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx on msdn

Comment: i've read the link and understand the problem, but I'm just too new at this to understand what I need to do to make it work on the first try.

Comment: try this....

Action action=new Action(()=>{
trafficManagementToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
timer1.Enabled = false; 
};

if (trafficManagementToolStripMenuItem.InvokeRequired) {
  trafficManagementToolStripMenuItem.Invoke(action);
} else {
  action();
}